# Visual Studio error on running a cpp file using Symbolic C++ library

Tags: c++, visual-studio, symbolic-math

I am trying to use the symbolic c++ library, I downloaded the library from this source:
http://issc.uj.ac.za/symbolic/symbolic.html

I opened the solution of the library, and under source files, I created a new cpp file, and I pasted this code taken from Wikipedia.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "symbolicc++.h"
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
 Symbolic x("x");
 cout << integrate(x+1, x);     // => 1/2*x^(2)+x
 Symbolic y("y");
 cout << df(y, x);              // => 0
 cout << df(y[x], x);           // => df(y[x],x)
 cout << df(exp(cos(y[x])), x); // => -sin(y[x])*df(y[x],x)*e^cos(y[x])
 return 0;
}
```

When I run the program, I get the following error message:

```
To register a module, you must provide a binary name.
Usage:regsvr32[/u][/s][/n][/i[:cmdline…
/u -Unregister server
/s -Silent; display no message boxes
/i -Call DllInstall passing it an optional [cmdline];
when used with /u calls dll uninstall
/n -do not call DllRegister Server; this option must be used with /i
```

What's the mistake I am doing here? Can someone help me to run the program?

Comment: How did you run regsvr32.exe while debugging?

Comment: I did not debug, I just run the program (CTRL+F5), and I have the cpp file as one of the cpp files in the library project.